# How to save bag of words datas in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

Here is my code :

```
sift=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
descriptors_unclustered=[]
dictionarysize=800
BOW=cv2.BOWKmeansTrainer(dictionarysize)
for p in training-paths :
    kp,dsc=sift.detectAndCompute(image,None)
    BOW.add(dsc)

dictionary=BOW.cluster()
bowdiction=cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(sift, cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2))
bowdiction.setvocabulary(dictionary)
```

I want to save this bowdiction data to use it later. I dont want to wait every time for these calculations so how can I save this data ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) for this

1. Save BOW to pickle:

   ```
   import pickle

   sift=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
   descriptors_unclustered=[]
   dictionarysize=800
   BOW=cv2.BOWKmeansTrainer(dictionarysize)
   for p in training-paths :
       kp,dsc=sift.detectAndCompute(image,None)
       BOW.add(dsc)

   with open('bow_pickle.pickle', 'wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(f)
   ```
2. Return the data from pickle:

   ```
   import pickle    
   with open('bow_pickle.pickle', 'rb') as f:
       BOW = pickle.load(f)    
   dictionary=BOW.cluster()
   bowdiction=cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(sift,cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2))
   bowdiction.setvocabulary(dictionary)
   ```

Comment: Can I save dictionary in the same manner ? Because especially "dictionary=BOW.cluster()" takes so much time

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. But as I came here and saw no answer, I tried a few things and this worked:

`dictionary=BOW.cluster()` is what takes most time. So you only need to save dictionary. Which is just an ndarray:

```py
np.savetxt('bow_dict.txt', dictionary)

loaded_dictionary = np.loadtxt('bow_dict.txt')
```

And then proceed with

```py
bowdiction=cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(sift,cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2))
bowdiction.setvocabulary(loaded_dictionary)
```

Comment: You may need to change the type:
loaded_dictionary = loaded_dictionary.astype(np.uint8)